# Environment variable to use tensorflow without cuDNN doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cudnn

I don't want to install cuDNN on a computer for which I haven't `sudo` privileges. For my TensorFlow model I don't need cuDNN, therefore I use the environment variable `TF_USE_CUDNN=0`. However, I get:

```
ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How I can use TensorFlow without cuDNN?

Comment: by installing TF without GPU support?

Comment: I want to use CUDA but without cuDNN, this is possible according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854940/tensorflow-gpu-is-cudnn-optional-couldnt-open-cuda-library-libcudnn-so

Comment: submit a bug report -- no sense in having TF_USE_CUDNN if it's not respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the [code that reads the environment variable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8a46d7a2998c4226560283bd35c163aeb724f593/tensorflow/core/util/use_cudnn.cc#L26) and its callers, the `TF_USE_CUDNN` environment variable only disables the use of cuDNN at runtime. Due to the way the standard TensorFlow-on-GPU distribution is linked, it still requires you to install the cuDNN library, because it will be loaded with the rest of the module. The easiest workaround would be to install cuDNN locally in your `$HOME/lib` directory, and set up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to look for the library there.